# Java 8 - How do I get a java.sql.Timestamp that is 24 hours ago?

Tags: java, sql, scala, timestamp, java-8

How do I obtain a [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) that represents 24 hours ago? I'm using JDK 8 via Scala.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which version of Java are you using? (I'd do most computations in java.time and then convert from an Instant, personally...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm on JDK 1.8, via Scala. I'm kind of new to Scala/Java so I'm unsure what to reach for in this case. I remember using Joda in the past however, so thinking of looking into that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Java 1.8, it's as simple as:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(instant);
```

You can use the overload of `now()` accepting a `Clock` to be more test-friendly (so you can test with a fake clock rather than the system clock). You might also want a static import of `ChronoUnit.HOURS` for readability - i.e. `Instant.now().minus(24, HOURS)`.

Note that this will be exactly 24 hours in the past - not "the same local time, but yesterday".